# brute force remote nop sled memory address

Tags: crackme, x86-64

ELF x64 binary on a remote server communicates via simple socket server in C.

After overflowing the buffer (total buffer is 2000, password buffer is less), overwriting the RIP, filling with NOP sled (512 nops), inserting a reverse bind shellcode on the top of that, finding out a perfect address (without `\x00`) in middle of nop sled which after sliding it will execute the shellcode.

- Remote server ASLR is off;
- Binary compiled without canary and can execute code from stack.
- No info leak AFAIK

I understand the many outcomes but if I decide to brute force the remote server to find the NOP-sled address.
Any good practice for that ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, I don't think brute-forcing memory addresses on remote server -especially for 64-bit address space- is not feasible. Maybe restricting searching space to certain stack addresses or leaking addresses someway could help your problem. I don't heard any other intelligent search method for this type of problem.

Comment: take a look https://github.com/Naetw/CTF-pwn-tips#leak-stack-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force is not the way you should look to in anything unless its your last resort. The address space of x64 is too large to get brute force to work. Look up on this technique called ROP(Return Oriented Programming). Currently you're bruteforcing the RIP, what if there's some code in the binary that will help you jump to your shellcode without bruteforcing and plus no PIE means that address is constant. When your control is getting transferred at `ret`, look at what other registers contain. You might find code such as `call eax` in the binary.

Comment: I can share the ROPgadget output, I have stack pivot but no rop chain, I do have "call rax" gadget but how do I populate rax to jump to nop sled ?

Comment: What are the contents of the registers? Do they refer to the buffer?

Comment: registers & stack https://hastebin.com/raw/axalohimur if you like I can edit the main question with the content

Comment: Can you share ROPgadget's output too?

Comment: ROPgadget & ropper output https://hastebin.com/raw/ehadepohod

Comment: @IddoE I think there are not so useful gadgets in the binary. Maybe some part of binary can help? Can you share the binary?